# PHP GD Merge images manipulated by function

Tags: php

Hello there sorry to be a bother to you guys,

I am trying to merge the images together after manipulating the image with a function i have created  but it is not working,

Any ideas?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function tester($image,$r,$g,$b) {
$img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $r,$g, $b);
return $img;
}
header("Content-type: image/png");


$image_1 = tester("1.png",123,111,0);
$image_2 = tester("2.png",123,111,0);
$x1 = imagesx($image_1);  
$y1 = imagesy($image_1); 
$x2 = imagesx($image_2);  
$y2 = imagesy($image_2); 


$slate = imagecreatetruecolor(max($x1, $x2), max($y1, $y2));
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($slate,0,255,0,127); 
imagefill($slate,0,0,$transparent); 

imagecopy($slate, $image_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image_1)-1, imagesy($image_1)-1); 
imagecopy($slate, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image_2)-1, imagesy($image_2)-1); 
imagepng($slate);
imagedestroy($slate);
```